# Rendering a partila view in dialog (pop up)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I try to display a popup by clicking a button using jquery, this button is placed at each end of a line corresponding to an element.

View :

```
<input  type="button" id="DetailButton" value="Details" onclick="GetDetails(this);"/>
```

Script :

```
function GetDetails(sender) {

 var IdElement = $($(sender).parent().parent()).find('input').val();

 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
        data: encodeURI("IdElement=" + IdElement) ,
        success: function (view) {

              //How to render a view in popup ?

       }

});

}
```

The dialog "DialogDetails" is in a partial View :

```
<div id="PopUpDetails" >
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">Element</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>              
                <%
                    foreach (var Item in Model.List)
                    { %>
                    <tr>                                     
                        <td>
                            <%:Html.DisplayFor(model => Item.IdElement) %>
                        </td>                      
                    </tr>
                <%} %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int IdElement)
{
       ElementViewModel model = new ElementViewModel ();

       return View("DialogDetails", model);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First return your view as a partial view. (View may be fine but I have not used that like this)

Then what you want to do is set the return result in the ajax call to be the content of your dialogue containing div.

e.g.

```
<div id="dialogDiv"><div>
```

then n the handler of your ajax call do this:

```
$('#dialogDiv').html(view);
$('#dialogDiv').dialog();
```

You must set the content first before calling the dialog function.

This works for me.

Comment: someone has another idea? I return the partial view in a div but not  in a dialog

Comment: Try this, in your partial view, add a listener for document.ready: $(document).ready(function(){// then call $('#dialogDiv').dialog(); in there.  maybe the view is not finished loaded.  or try and use a timeout before calling it after setting the view.  This definitely works for me.